# warnings filter precedence

Tags: python, warnings

```py
import warnings

def warn():
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('always')
        warnings.warn('warning')
        
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    warn()
```

```
warn.py:6: UserWarning: warning
  warnings.warn('warning')
```

I was thinking that the `'ignore'` filter would apply but it seems the `'always'` filter within the function is taking priority. Is this the expected behavior? Is there any way to ignore a warning in this case? I am importing something with `simplefilter('always')`, so I do not have control, but I would like to ignore it.

Comment: How would I go about making the warnings maintainers aware of this? I do not see the option to open an Issue on the [repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/warnings.py)